# Simulating arrow key presses in android

Tags: android, key, inject, arrow-keys

I am currently working on an app that simulates the d-pad (up, down, left, and right). The problem is that I can't figure out how to send those key presses to other applications.

Currently, I am using Instrumentation and it works perfectly fine in the activity of my app.
Here is the snippet of the arrow key left code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {         
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                 
                        new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
                    }   
                }).start();
```

The problem with this implementation is that due to an android security feature, I cannot send key presses to other applications.
After searching up different ways to injecting key presses, I came across this [article](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.UUfRUReOR8E). However, after trying the example code, it doesn't seem to work. I poked around and found out that android doesn't seem to have an input device for the keyboard. When I scan for different input devices, I get stuff such as orientation sensor and etc. Here is a pic of all the input devices on my phone (T-959 Galaxy S).

[image: input devices]

As you can see, none of these devices is a keyboard. I have a feeling that this is because my phone does not have a physical keyboard. (cypress is the capacitive keys, aries is the volume buttons, and mxt224 is the touchscreen controller)

After a bit more of research, I found that the accessibility api in android has limit capabilities for injecting events, but those are only very basic things such as switching view focus and etc ([AccessibilityNodeInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html)). However, I have a feeling that I might be able to extend it to support arrow key presses.

So currently, I am very confused on where to go. Has anyone ever done anything like this before? It seems that the simple injection of arrow keys (nothing else) is very frustrating due to the security features in Android. All suggestions are welcomed.

EDIT: I might not have been very clear, but I am fine with building this for rooted phones only. Only requirement is that this app has to run standalone on the phone without being hooked up to any external keyboards via otg or the computer via adb.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to simulate DPAD key press events few days back and I did find a solution which has its own limitation.

Arrow key press can be simulated using **adb** command`input keyevent <keycode>`. 
So if you want to simulate a DPAD LEFT key press then use the adb command`adb input keyevent 21`.

To reuse this bit of code and scale it forward, I created a standalone swing application where i select the device to which i need to send the key events and I can use the existing keyboard of my computer to type in the keys.[I map the keyboard key codes to android key codes].

I am further scaling the application by including remote and game pad buttons, once done, i'll upload the project on git.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will I be able to run this on the phone without being connected to the computer? Do I just run it as a shell command with su root access? This seems very simple, but I feel that this still depends on the input devices(I may be wrong). I will love to see this, because it sounds like a very simple solution to my problem.

Comment: the solution i suggested needs to be connected to the computer since i am using the computer keyboard. but you can do the same by dispatching shell commands from the android device

Comment: Is the keyevent 21 universal across all devices for a DPAD LEFT event?  I would assume yes since it is an adb command, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: I tried running input keyevent 21 in my service with root permissions, but it still doesn't work. The key injection still needs to pass through the android system, so it is still getting picked up as a security breach. Works perfectly fine within my app (has a little delayed response), but if I try to execute the command outside my app, it sends an error that is the same to what I get from the Instrumentation method.

Comment: did you sign your application with the system (platform) key ? that might solve the issue with your previous code for injecting pointer events

Comment: no, I did not sign my app. the problem is that I don't think I will be able to publish my app onto the market if I sign it with the system key.

Comment: until and unless u sign ur app with system privileges you will get a security exception

Answer (score 0):

IF you intention is to create an application that works on non rooted phones perhaps your best bet is to implement a new InputMethod using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html

Comment: Will this conflict with the keyboard that the user is using? I think you can only have one active input method at a time as described by the inputmethodmanager.